# sed returning empty line on second pass

Tags: url, variables, sed, substitution

I have a configuraton file that I am editing and on the first pass the is correctly changed but on the next two lines sed returns the lines blank.

The lines to be edited are

```
word.word.word.database=dbase
word.word.word.username=someone
word.word.word.password=someone
```

The sed commands I am using are

```
cat config.file | \sed -e "s/database/$dbname/" > config.file.1

cat config.file.1 | \sed -e "s/username/$dbuser/" > config.file.2

cat config.file.2 | \sed -e "s/database/$password/" > config.file.3

 cp config.file.3 config.file
```

The end result is

```
word.word.word.database=dbname
word.word.word.username=
word.word.word.password=
```

Can't figure out what is going wrong with this. Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$dbname` , `$dbuser` and `$password` are begin treated like shell variables, hence the leading dollar signs. If you're trying to incorporate shell vars, try:

```
 sed -i -e "s/database/$dbname/" -e "s/username/$dbuser/" -e "s/password/$password/" config.file
```

Notice that I've added the `-i` flag to the above command. It enables in-place editing using `GNU sed`. Other types of `sed` require an extension to be set, like: `-i.bak` and this creates a back up file; in your case this would be: `config.bak`.

If you're just looking to get the full list of results, either drop the dollarsigns or use single quotes. For example:

```
sed -i -e "s/database/dbname/" -e "s/username/dbuser/" -e "s/password/password/" config.file
```

or

```
sed -i -e 's/database/$dbname/' -e 's/username/$dbuser/' -e 's/password/$password/' config.file
```

***EDIT1:***

If I've completely mis-understood your question, try this:

```
sed -i -e "s/\(.*database=\).*/\1dbname/" -e "s/\(.*username=\).*/\1dbuser/" -e "s/\(.*password=\).*/\1password/" config.file
```

Results:

```
word.word.word.database=dbname
word.word.word.username=dbuser
word.word.word.password=password
```

***EDIT2:***

If you have shell vars labelled `$dbname` , `$dbuser` and `$password`:

```
sed -i -e "s/\(.*database=\).*/\1$dbname/" -e "s/\(.*username=\).*/\1$dbuser/" -e "s/\(.*password=\).*/\1$password/" config.file
```

Comment: I am using the linux shell script and I am reading in variables from a file. That is why the $ signs were there. But do the 1's have the same function as the $ signs?

Comment: @user1794918: No; the `\1`'s are used [to keep part of the matching pattern](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-4). I see what you're trying to do here. I've added dollarsigns so that `sed` can interpret the variables. Please see the edit.

Comment: One last thing. The whole command that I am using now with your instruction is

Comment: @user1794918: I think you may have forgotten to paste the command?